# Alternative to partition problem dynamic programming

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

This question is regarding the famous partition problem.

I was doing some learning on this problem and saw that most of the solutions follow "partition a set into two such that their difference is minimal", or "determine whether there are two subsets s.t their sum is the same"

I would like to know if there is a solution to the question: "partition a set into two such that their difference is some value d"

Maybe their difference is 1, or 2, for example.

```
subset({3,4,9}, diff=2) = [{9}, {3,4}]
```

because the sum of subset 1 is 9, and of subset two is 7, which gives us the difference 2 as wanted.

Is there such a problem like this?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is simply equivalent to [subset-sum one](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/subset-sum-problem-dp-25/).
Solve subset sum for `sum=overall_sum/2 + d/2` and you'll get needed subsets as solution and the rest